# Pass function by reference in onclick event Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript, jQuery. I need to pass `function` by reference in `onClick` event.
Here is what I'm trying but not working.

```
function onClickHandler() {
    console.log("on click handler");
}

function renderButton(callback) {
    $("#root").append(
        '<div style="text-align:right; padding:10px 10px;">\
            <button onclick="' +
        callback +
        '">Collect Hadiths</button>\
        </div>'
    );
}

renderButton(onClickHandler);
```

Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `onclick` handler after you added your button to the DOM.

```
function onClickHandler() {
    console.log("on click handler");
}

function renderButton(callback) {
    $("#root").append(
        '<div style="text-align:right; padding:10px 10px;">\
            <button id="button">Collect Hadiths</button>\
        </div>'
    );
    $("#button").click(callback);
}

renderButton(onClickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the click event to the generated element by using the code below

```js
function onClickHandler() {
    console.log("on click handler");
}

function renderButton(callback) {
    $('<div style="text-align:right; padding:10px 10px;">\
            <button>Collect Hadiths</button>\
        </div>'
    ).appendTo("#root").find('button').click(callback);
}

renderButton(onClickHandler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
function onClickHandler() {
    console.log("on click handler");
}

function renderButton(callback) {
    // Create the button and add the click event
    const button = $('<button>Collect Hadiths</button>');
    $(button).click(callback);

    // Create the div and append the button to it
    const div = $('<div style="text-align:right; padding:10px 10px;"></div>');
    $(div).append(button);

    // Now add to the root
    $("#root").append(div);
}

renderButton(onClickHandler);
```